# Program receives signal - gdb

Tags: c, gdb

For the below [question](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/C/node7.html#SECTION00730000000000000000),

`Exercise 12335 - Write a C program to read through an array of any type. Write a C program to scan through this array to find a particular value.`

Here is my solution:

```
#include<stdio.h>
enum types
  {
    integer,
    character,
    floatValue
  };
void f(void *, enum types);
void doSomething(void *, enum types);
int main(){
  int a[] ={1,2,3};
  enum types type = integer;
  f(a, type);
}

void f(void *ptr, enum types type){
  switch(type){
    case(integer):
      if(sizeof((int *)ptr)/sizeof(int) > 1){
        doSomething(&((int *)ptr)[1], type); // Print second element
      }
      break;
    case(character):
      if(sizeof((char *)ptr)/sizeof(char) > 1){
        doSomething(&((int *)ptr)[1], type); // Print second element
      }
      break;
    case(floatValue):
      if(sizeof((float *)ptr)/sizeof(float) > 1){
        doSomething(&((int *)ptr)[1], type); // Print second element
      }
      break;
  }
}

void doSomething(void *ptr, enum types type){
  switch(type){
    case(integer):
      printf("%d", *(int *)ptr);
      break;
    case(character):
      printf("%c", *(char *)ptr);
      break;
    case(floatValue):
      printf("%f", *(float *)ptr);
      break;
  }
}
```

---

```
> gcc -g temp.c -o program.exe
> gdb program.exe
```

Below is the gdb output:

### [image]

### [image]

Question:

Why does  `program.exe` not work?

Comment: Are you trying to get the length of the array with `sizeof((int *)ptr)/sizeof(int)`? You can only do that with an array, not with a pointer.

Comment: Get a stack trace from gdb and find out which line in the program caused the signal.

Comment: @Barmar Stack trace is updated in the question

Comment: The error is happening when calling `SetThreadName()`, but there's nothing like that in the code you posted. Did you post the whole program?

Comment: @Barmar  BTW, this code is working on *http://rextester.com/l/c_online_compiler_gcc*. Can I gdb code in some online tool? rather than cygwin env on my laptop?

Comment: GDB will only run in an environment where you have local control, not in an arbitrary online environment (unless they have an option to provide gdb access).  My guess is rextester uses linux, which works fine for me also.  One a sidenote - the code as is in your question does not work - it doesn't provide useful output...but it won't crash.

Comment: @roelofs I got one http://www.onlinegdb.com/

Comment: There you go then :)  Might I suggest installing a linux VM on your machine, instead of using Cygwin?  Generally quicker (and with more control) than using online tools if you're going to be doing this regularly.

Comment: @roelofs  Not regularly, preparing for Arista Networks interview

Comment: Good luck with the interview!

Comment: GDB is designed for Unix; "received signal ?" is probably a bug with the WIndows port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not find the size of an array based solely on the pointer (the pointer is only an address - it does not contain any information about what it points to).

Below is a solution where the function is modified, and the array size is passed in as a parameter.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
enum types
  {
    integer,
    character,
    floatValue
  };
void f(void *, enum types, int a_size);
void doSomething(void *, enum types);
int main(){
  int a[] ={1,2,3};
  enum types type = integer;
  f(a, type, sizeof(a));
}

void f(void *ptr, enum types type, int a_size){
  switch(type){
    case(integer):
      if(a_size/sizeof(int) > 1){
        doSomething(&((int *)ptr)[1], type); // Print second element
      }
      break;
    case(character):
      if(a_size/sizeof(char) > 1){
        doSomething(&((int *)ptr)[1], type); // Print second element
      }
      break;
    case(floatValue):
      if(a_size/sizeof(float) > 1){
        doSomething(&((int *)ptr)[1], type); // Print second element
      }
      break;
  }
}

void doSomething(void *ptr, enum types type){
  switch(type){
    case(integer):
      printf("%d", *(int *)ptr);
      break;
    case(character):
      printf("%c", *(char *)ptr);
      break;
    case(floatValue):
      printf("%f", *(float *)ptr);
      break;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if it will fix your gdb issue (I'm on Linux, not Windows, and not receiving any signals), but the program will run correctly.

[UPDATE]

This is a style thing, but I would update the `f` function to look like this:

```c
void f(void *ptr, enum types type, int a_size){
  int unit_size;
  switch(type){
    case(integer):
      unit_size = sizeof(int);
      break;
    case(character):
      unit_size = sizeof(char);
      break;
    case(floatValue):
      unit_size = sizeof(float);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  if((a_size/unit_size) > 1){
    doSomething(&((int *)ptr)[1], type); // Print second element
  }
}
```

It makes it more readable, quicker to add different types, and if you change the call to `doSomething`, you only have to modify it in one place.

Comment: Do you think the solution can still be optimised?

Comment: Well, for one, you don't search for a particular value - you're just printing the second element in the array.  I would also change f to set a single size variable based on type, so you don't repeat the `doSomething` lines.